# In Android Studio, the shortcut F8 for "step over" easily gets influenced when focusing to emulator by accident

Tags: android-studio

Sometimes I got deceived when I press F8 to "step over" in debug mode because the window focus will be switched from my code editor to emulator when my ap was run up.
But the shortcut F8 in emulator will disconnect the debugging. It's annoying. How could I change the shorcut F8 in code editor and emulator. I want to separate them. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, Preferences > Keymap, and in the search box for that preferences pane, enter "step over".

Comment: before anyone goes bonky twice looking for it, AS 1.5.1 had those at File > Settings > Keymap